# Given a list of angular rates and timestamps, how do you correctly obtain the angles?

Tags: integration, angle, related-rates

There are 5 dynamic angular rates `ω_k` (°/s) for 5 different time epochs `t_k`.
For each time epoch, the respective angle `θ_k` shall be calculated.

In general, this applies: `θ = ω * ∆t`. Assuming an initial/prior angle `θ(t=0)` can be disregarded, how are the angles of the other time epochs calculated? Do I look at the angular rate of the current time epoch and multiply that by the time difference between the current and previous time epoch to get my current angle? Or do I use the angular rate of by previous time epoch?

Which one of these equations is correct?

```
θ_k = ω_k * (t_k - t_k-1)

θ_k = ω_k-1 * (t_k - t_k-1)
```

Comment: You're asking whether a left Riemann sum or a right Riemann sum is correct. Neither is correct. Both are approximations of the integral.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear approximation average could relate to central value:

$$ ( θ_k-\theta _{k-1})  =\frac{ ω_k + ω_{k-1}}{2}. (t_k - t_{k-1})$$